# Function Series Pointwise and Uniform convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Check the function series $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, f_{n}:]0,\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  for pointwise and uniform convergence and prove your results.

a) $f_{ n }\left( x \right) =\frac { n^{ 2 } }{ x } $

b) $f_{ n }\left( x \right) =\frac { x }{ n^{ 2 } } $

c) $f_{ n }\left( x \right) =\frac { n+x }{ nx } $

d) $ f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{for } x \in ]0,n]\\ 0& \text{for} \ x \in ]n,\infty [ \end{cases} $

---

I am not sure if correct but i found the pointwise convergence for **a)** to be $\infty$ and for **b)** it is $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ x\frac { 1 }{ n^{ 2 } }  } =0$ for **c)** $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { n+x }{ nx }  } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ (\frac { n }{ nx } +\frac { x }{ nx } ) } =\frac { 1 }{ x } $ whats with d) ? and how should i check for uniform convergence ?

Comment: d) Draw the graphs of the functions and see where would they converge to. For uniform convergence, find $\sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ and see whether these $\sup$s converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- a) $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge pointwise nor uniform. $(\frac{n^2}{x})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is not bounded and therefore it does not converge. Because it does not converge pointwise it won't converge uniform too.
- b) $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n^2}$ converges pointwise but not uniform.
- c) $f_n(x)=\frac{n+x}{nx}$ converges uniform and therefore pointwise too.
- d) Converges Pointwise against $1$ but not uniform